# changing flash file width and height in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, flash

i have a flash file which i need to display in a aspx file . the width and height of the fla file is 500 and 600px . but i need to show it in 300 and 300 px. i set the width and height in aspx file. but the flash file not coming in proper. some part of the fla file got hiden. i need to display the flash file fully but in small size .

```
        <div style="Height:300px; width:300px">
       <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"                  

      codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/
       shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="105%">
       <param name="movie" value="events.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
 <embed src="events.swf"
  quality="high"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  wmode="transparent"
  width="100%"  
  height="105%"
  top="100px"   
  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
  allowScriptAccess="always" />
 </object></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe has to do with how the FLA is constructed and embedded, little has to do with ASP.NET as it is a server-side technology.  To achieve such, the "scale" of the Flash would need to be set as `showAll`, you may achieve so by adding `scale="showAll"` in the `EMBED` tag and `<param name="scale" value="showAll" />` in the `OBJECT` tag.

However, it is possible that your Flash movie may overwrite the value scale value to "noScale".  This is done by setting the `scaleMode` of `Stage` to `noScale` or other undesired values.  You would need to go through the sources of your Flash movie to remove that overwrite.  If the source of the movie is a Flex application, by default a Flex application's `scaleMode` is `noScale`